# ¿Validar TextBox que solo permita numeros enteros MS Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Cordial saludo compañeros, resulta que tengo un formulario en MS Visual Basic y le estoy realizando las respectivas validaciones a los botones y cajas de texto.
En las cajas de texto debe validarse que solo reciba numeros enteros, no permita decimales ni texto. para validar que no se pueda ingresar texto use el siguiente codigo en el textbox:

```
Private Sub txtlevantamiento_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtlevantamiento.TextChanged
        'Funcion para que solo se pueda escribir numeros en el textbox
        If Not IsNumeric(txtlevantamiento.Text) Then
            txtlevantamiento.Text = " "

        End If

    End Sub
```

¿Que condicional adicional podría agregarle para que solo se pueda escribir números enteros y evitar que escriban decimales?

Comment: te deja ingresar decimales todavia?

Comment: Aunque el duplicado es en C#, en vb es lo mismo, solo fijate en el evento que se usa (`txtlevantamiento.KeyPress()`) y copia el código del método `SoloNumeros`

Comment: SI Raul Cacacho,  aun me deja ingresar decimales.

Comment: Pikoh, pondría ese código y método después del condicional anterior que mostré?

Comment: A ver. En lugar de el código que tienes que usa `TextChanged`,debes usar el evento `KeyPress`. En la ventana de diseño, pincha en el textbox, y en las ventanta de propiedades busca el evento y da doble click para que te genere el metodo controlador del evento. Y luego es solo pegar el código de la pregunta que te enlacé

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el evento keyPress de tu caja de texto. Anexa el código siguiente, la cual debería funcionar, no permite caracteres más que números y teclas de control del teclado (supr, borrar)

```
 Private Sub txtlevantamiento_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtlevantamiento.KeyPress
            If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
                e.Handled = False
            ElseIf Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
                e.Handled = False
            Else
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: Correcto, ya edite la respuesta, fue un error de visualización, gracias por la observación.

Comment: El campo no aceptará coma ni punto, solo números !

Comment: Gracias Silvestre, ya lo probe y me funciono perfectamente